# como usar una fuente de iconos en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica, icons

Tengo una fuente de iconos personalizada que hice con ayuda de icoMoon, quiero usar esa fuente en un formulario de windows forms c# como lo hago?, no uso FontAwesome por que hay iconos que no encuentro

Comment: Te coloque una respuesta, para la proxima deberias agregar el codigo que hiciste y sobre eso poder ayudarte, para que sea mas facil el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo la fuente instalada en la carpeta de windows/Font

lo que debes hacer es instanciar una fuente con su nombre (el nombre de tu fuente):

```
        FontFamily font = new FontFamily("fontello");            
        System.Drawing.Font fuente = new System.Drawing.Font(font,15);
```

Segundo le seteas la fuente a tu componente y el codigo en la propiedad `Text`

```
        button1.Font = fuente;
        button1.Text = "\ue813";
```

Si queres ver los codigos de tu fuente, podes hacerlos desde esta pagina.
[https://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/](http://%5Bhttps://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/%5D%5B1%5D)